# How Do I Say If This Statment Is Being Presented Then Show THis Else SHow That

Tags: php, mysql

### EDIT

I am now getting an error:

```
  Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/jahedhus/public_html/system/vote.php on line 126
```

My php code is as follows:

```
    <?php 

$id = $_GET['election'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE election_id = '$id' AND ni = '". $_SESSION['ni']."'" )

or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {

   $sql="SELECT * FROM elections WHERE status = 'in_progress' AND election_id = '$id'";

$result1=mysql_query($sql);

$options="";
$party2="";
$party3="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><h5>" . $row['name_of_election']. "</h5><hr></td>";
    echo "</td>";


    $idd=$row["party1"];
    $thing=$row["party1"];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$idd\">".$thing;

    $idd=$row["party2"];
    $thing=$row["party2"];
    $party2.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$idd\">".$thing; 

    $idd=$row["party3"];
    $thing=$row["party3"];
    $party3.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$idd\">".$thing;

}
}
?>

<?php if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0) : ?>
  <form action="votecasted.php?election=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">

    <span id="spryselect1">
    <label for="vote">Vote</label>&nbsp;
    <select size=1" name="vote" id="vote">
        <option selected="selected">Select Your Desired Party</option>
        <?=$options?>
        <?=$party2?>
        <?=$party3?>
</select>
    <span class="selectRequiredMsg">*</span></span><br />

<br />    <input name="" type="submit" value="Vote" />
  </form>

<?php else : ?>
    You cannot post vote anymore.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Line 126 is where it says:

```
<?php if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0) : ?>
```

Its weird becuase once a user has voted, it shows the error message whereby if the user hasnt voted, it says 'You cannot post vote anymore'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand the question, you just have to check `$result` to be different from `false`. I'd suggest you to use the following syntax for embedded PHP:

```
<?php if ($result) : ?>
    <form></form>
<?php else : ?>
    Something else
<?php endif; ?>
```

In your case, with some more SQL Injection checks:

```
<?php 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['election']);
$ni = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['ni']);
$votes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE election_id = '$id' AND ni = '$ni'" )
or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($votes) == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM elections WHERE status = 'in_progress' AND election_id = '$id'";
    $elections = mysql_query($sql);

    $options="";
    $party2="";
    $party3="";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($elections)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><h5>" . $row['name_of_election']. "</h5><hr></td>";
        echo "</td>";
        $idd=$row["party1"];
        $thing=$row["party1"];
        $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$idd\">".$thing;

        $idd=$row["party2"];
        $thing=$row["party2"];
        $party2.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$idd\">".$thing; 

        $idd=$row["party3"];
        $thing=$row["party3"];
        $party3.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$idd\">".$thing;
    }
}
?>

<?php if (mysql_num_rows($votes) == 0) : ?>
    <form action="votecasted.php?election=<?=$id?>" method="post">
        <span id="spryselect1">
        <label for="vote">Vote</label>&nbsp;
        <select size="1" name="vote" id="vote">
            <option selected="selected">Select Your Desired Party</option>
            <?=$options?>
            <?=$party2?>
            <?=$party3?>
        </select>
        <span class="selectRequiredMsg">*</span></span><br />
        <br />
        <input name="" type="submit" value="Vote" />
  </form>
<?php else : ?>
    You cannot post vote anymore.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Because it's easier to read (and code) when jumping in and out of PHP like that. It only saves a few characters, but you may save your sanity in doing so.

Comment: @jeff please have a look at my main post once again

Comment: @MohemaBurhan, if there's a problem with my answer just state what am I getting wrong. Every time I read the question this seems an appropriate answer to me.

Comment: my form is still being dislpayed even though the user has voted already. however the values do not show up in the drop down which is a good thing but i would prefer if the form would not show up at all

Comment: please do have a look at my editted post becuase i might be doing something wrong which you may be able to figure out. thanks a lot

Comment: @MohemaBurhan, see the last two lines of this answer.

Comment: im sorry i accidently editted your post earlier rather then editting mine. i cant see your updated post unless you decline my edit.

Comment: @MohemaBurhan, I've already declined it.

Comment: @MohemaBurhan, anyway here it is: You have to change the first $result into something else, let's say `$result1`. Then you do `if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0) :` in the code I've posted up here.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli please check my edit once again.

Comment: @MohemaBurhan, try my new code.